# Setting Objects Table IndexPath to Object Attributes?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data

I want to save the index paths my objects are in within a tableview as an attribute in core data.

This is so the user can rearrange them as they please and I can save the positions and reload them in different views in that order.

Im not sure where i should be making this save, as you cant access table index paths externally to table functions?

Currently I am using

```
for uniqueUserExercise in queryResults {
  uniqueUserExercise.arrayPosition = ??
}
```

where `let queryResults = try self.managedObjectContext.fetch(request)`

and uniqueUserExercise is an exercise object in the array of query results

where ?? would be the way to find out the indexpath of each item in the tableview

Any ideas how I can achieve this? the result for example would be, whatever object is sat at indexpath 3 having a 2 saved, the one at 5 having a 4 saved (as obviously they start from 0)

Im just not sure how to access this data in an external function to the usual row setup stuff?

Appreciate any support in this

Comment: i am very excited to help you can you please explain more? what exactly you want ?

Answer (score 0):

UITableViewDataSource has two methods that support the reordering of rows: tableView(*:canMoveRowAt:) and tableView(*:moveRowAt:to:). If you read the notes at the beginning of UITableView, you can find out when each of those methods is called -- at events like inserting, deleting or dragging. You can then use the information those methods provide you with to update the "myIndex" attribute of the NSManagedObject concerned.